# Inequality of the probability of a sequence of events

Tags: probability

Let $(A_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of events in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and
$$ A=\{ \omega\in \Omega: \omega\in A_n \text{ for infinitely many }n \}. $$
Show that
$$ \mathbb{P}(A)\le\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_k) $$
for all $n$.

I tried to expresss $A$ as some combinations of $A_k$ but I cannot construct for arbitrary $n$. I also tried induction but had no clues.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\geq n}A_m.$$